# simultaneous page load and ajax call

Tags: asp.net, ajax, load

I have a web application with some pages take quite a long time to load because of what they have to do in code behind. I would like to show what is going on to the user by showing the different status of the process.

I was thinking about calling recursively (by ajax) a page which ready a value in the session. This value is set by the page that take time to load.
The problem is that the page called by ajax is not executed while the other page load is finished.
Is there some way to do that?

Thanks advance

Comment: How long do they take? What is it you're doing server side and what do you plan to move client side?

Comment: It can take minutes to proceed. On the server side I have a database containing file, this is this file I need to retrieve to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual pattern here is to load an initial status page that triggers an AJAX call to retrieve the final version of the page, overwriting the original with the result of your AJAX call when it completes.

Comment: What if the final version of the page results to a file to download (header content-type changes)?

Comment: Then return a page with a link from which the user can download the file.

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't do this, the file is not physically on the server but in a database.

Comment: Err..OK, so you want to display HTML to the user indicating the process will take some time and then, once processing is complete, automagically download a non-HTML result? I suppose you could initially return an HTML "please wait" page, trigger an AJAX call to instruct the server to compose the intended result, wait for the result to be complete, then redirect the current page to the newly created downloadable result, but this would require the result to be cached on the server and also violates the one-click, one-result model of the Web.

Comment: It's almost what I did, the difference is that I don't use Ajax to call the final page but do a window.location.replace = mypage.

Comment: Umm..replacing window.location *is* a redirect. :-)

Comment: sorry, what I wanted to say is that, with way when the result is complete the page is automatically redirected. No need to wait for it. It's what you wanted to say?

Comment: Since your processing of the result takes time (potentially longer than your users or their browsers will wait), you need some indication that the result is ready to be retrieved. This is why I suggested an AJAX call to trigger processing the result which only returns when the result is ready for retrieval, at which point, the AJAX onSuccess callback would redirect the browser to retrieve the newly composed result.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will make some test in this way to see if it works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the part of the code that takes a long time and call it asynchronously (e.g. as a WebMethod) on page load, e.g. if using jQuery, on `document.ready`. You could also fake this using an `UpdatePanel` which is set to conditional refresh, and the code is never run by default. Then refresh it from script using `__doPostBack('updatePanelUniqueID','')`.

Comment: I've tried your solution but it doesn't seems to work, the ajax code is continuously called but the code behind is not executed while the other is loading.

Comment: Which one? Can you update this question with  some details of how you implemented this?

Comment: I've tried both, in the first one I've put the method in a web service (in the same website) and call it from the page that was taking long to load. For the second one I've inserted the updatepanel in the "main" page and refresh it by the __doPostBack. In the updatepanel I just added a method to call the code behind of the page to read the session.