# Is there a way to load a webpage in pieces using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, pageload

I have a lot of data that I'm calling from my server and want to 'decrease' the load time that it takes to render the page with the data. (I use decrease in quotes because I know it doesn't actually decrease load time it only gives the illusion of decreased load time).

I understand that AJAX is the method here, but how exactly would I implement this sort of behavior in ASP.NET?

Comment: could you use ajax to load the page content piece by piece?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216787/simultaneous-page-load-and-ajax-call/6216878#6216878

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use Ajax to show a "loading..." animation for areas that are time-intensive, thereby allowing the page to be rendered during the delay.

Another idea is to employ caching where possible to eliminate the database hit.

Answer (score 0):

There's no one answer. There are conventions such as placing synchronous Javascript calls at the bottom of your page (just before `</body>`). You could also `Paginate` your data so that you only need to get a few sets at a time, making the calls quicker. You should also compress all images to a reasonable amount so that the quality remains but the bytes transferred over the wire decreases. You should also read [Yahoo's guide on best practices](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).